# get the list of available directories at specified path using batch file(CMD)

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a script which will return me list of directories available at the path which I specify.

Could not anybody help. I don't have any idea of cmd commands.

thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use For Batch file:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Users\") do dir /ad /on /b "%%a"
```

If User contains 3 folders,
This will print:

Folder1 Folder2 Folder3

If you want all sub-folders list with full path use

```
 for /d %%a in ("C:\Users\") do dir /ad /on /S /b "%%a"
```

This will print:
C:/Users/Folder1
C:/Users/Folder1/Data
C:/Users/Folder2
C:/Users/Folder3

Comment: is there any advantage to use `for` instead of just `dir /ad /on /S /b C:\Users\`?

Comment: @vaibhav nice reply thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /ad "c:\somepath"
```

Type `dir /?` and `help`.

Comment: maybe add `/b` for cleaner output

Comment: This is by far the simplest answer to this question, and the one that I would have provided myself.